# Get value of src attribute from NSString

Tags: ios4

So I have a long string that has text like:

```
src="http://antibride.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/AttendantsA6.1.11.jpg" alt="" width="197" height="229"
```

and I want to chop out the value for that src attribute only, I mean that link only for the image.
How can i do it on Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is iOS 4.0, you can use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSString * myString = @" src=\"http://antibride.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/AttendantsA6.1.11.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"197\" height=\"229\"";

NSRegularExpression * expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=src=\").+?(?=\")"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                               error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult * result = [expression firstMatchInString:myString
                                                       options:0 
                                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

NSString * link = [myString substringWithRange:result.range];
NSLog(@"Link = %@", link);
```

You can use `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` method to get all such links available.